# Transfer configurable script using chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I need to implement a cookbook that allows the customer do to the following with chef:

- Configure the list of file that has to be transferred
- Copy the configured file (in this case script file) to the node on which the cookbook is being executed
- Execute the script that are configured as to be executed

I did not find a way to transfer configurable file. Which is the best way to do that in CHEF?

Comment: What's "the list of file"? What script? Makes storing the script in git sense to you? Deploying an running it via chef is easy then. But you sound pretty unclear about what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Chef is not a file transfer mechanism other than the simplistic one offered in `cookbook_file` and `remote_directory`. Figure out how you would do this without Chef and then write your recipe code to match.

Comment: you are right. I explained to the customer that the best way to do that is to use cookbook_file. So whenever a new script is developed the cookbook has to be updated and uploaded.